# PHP's rawurlencode is not equal to JavaScripts escape! Why?

Tags: php, javascript, escaping, urlencode

i realized when i used urlencode or rawurlencode in PHP encoding the simple character § (paragraph) i get the following result: "%C2%A7".

But when i use escape in Javascript to encode that character, i get only "%A7".

In this case i have encoding problems when sending/receiving data between the server running PHP and the javascript client trying to fetch the data via ajax/jquery.

I want to be able to write any type of text i want. For this i encode the text and send it to the backend php script, escaping the data and sending. When i retrieve it, on php side i take the data from mysql and do rawurlencode and send it back.

Both sides, work in UTF-8 mode. jquery ajax function is called with `"contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded:charset=UTF-8"`, mysql server is set for UTF-8 both for client and server, and the php script starts echoing with `header( "application/x-www-form-urlencoded:charset=UTF-8");`

Why is PHP producing that %C2 thing, which generates the character Â on javascript side.

Coult somebody help?

Comment: Looking at the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it appears a user named omid [had the same trouble](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php#96394).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago and found the solution :

```
function rawurlencode (str) {
    str = (str+'').toString();        
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28').
                                                                                    replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A');
}
```

The code is taken from here - http://phpjs.org/functions/rawurlencode:501
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that info. But this is for the javascript side. The javascript side looks ok, as the data is correctly stored in my mysql db. Retrieving it from my php side is the problem. So i need something in PHP to get the right encoding for §

Comment: ah crap, just got it. i have to use encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent. Then the encoding and decoding works fine between javascript and php. Your rawurlencode is the right one, thanks Radoslav.

Answer (score 3):

It's clearly a charset íssue:

```
[adrian@cheops3:~]> php -r 'echo rawurlencode(utf8_encode("§"));'
%C2%A7
[adrian@cheops3:~]> php -r 'echo rawurlencode("§");'
%A7
```

(the terminal is obviously not running in utf8 mode)

If you have a literal `§` in your PHP code ensure that the *php file* is saved as UTF8.

Comment: Interesting. So in your case rawurlencode("§"); returned only %A7. But in my case i get %C2%A7. And you think this is coming from my php files encoding. How can i check the files encoding? The thing is even in my terminal i get %C2%A7. So is my terminal non-utf8? how can i be sure that its pure utf8. my terminals encoding is set to utf-8.

Comment: Hm ok, i did this: php -r 'echo rawurlencode(utf8_decode("§"));'
And it returned only %A7. What does that mean?

Comment: If you get %C2%A7 it's UTF8; if it's not, you get %A7. If you are using vim you can set the file encoding by using `:set fenc=utf8` (or latin1)